# Get original message headers using EWS for bounced emails

Tags: c#, email, c#-4.0, exchangewebservices

I have done some research and also some code testing with Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 to realise that in bounced e-mails, the headers are being removed. One of the articles I referred to was this: [Detecting bounced messages by return-path header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104404/detecting-bounced-messages-by-return-path-header).

The problem I have is trying retrieve custom headers from bounced e-mail, but it seems impossible according to my research. The other solution that was mentioned in the above article was using the return-path address.

However, when I access my web e-mail using Microsoft Outlook Web App, and checking the e-mail that was bounced back to my address, I was able to view the original message headers. So, is it possible to use EWS managed API to retrieve the original message headers?

The original message header is follows:

```
Diagnostic information for administrators:

    Generating server: MXG001.domain.com

    email.that.do.not.exist.1234567890@gmail.com
    gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com # #SMTP#

    Original message headers:

    Return-Path: sender@domain.com
    Received: from MXG001.domain.com (unknown [127.0.0.1]) by IMSVA (Postfix)
     with ESMTP id 1484C26805C  for ;
     Wed, 29 Aug 2012 20:07:56 +1000 (EST)
    Received: from EZY106 (unknown [10.32.8.141])     by MXG001.domain.com
     (Postfix) with ESMTP id 6F7B026805B      for
     email.that.do.not.exist.1234567890@gmail.com; Wed, 29 Aug 2012 20:07:55
     +1000 (EST)
    Reply-To: myemail@domain.com
    X-CustomHeader1: 0E591306-9997-4E35-954E-F36A069AF8B4
    X-CustomHeader2: 1F80DCBF-2F93-49A4-90C0-00E79763B916
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Sender: domain sender@domain.com
    From: myemail@domain.com
    To: email.that.do.not.exist.1234567890@gmail.com
    Date: Wed, 29 Aug 2012 18:10:13 +0800
    Subject: Test e-mail tracking 3
    Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
    Message-ID: 20120829100755.6F7B026805B@MXG001.domain.com
    X-TM-AS-MML: No
    X-TM-AS-Product-Ver: IMSVA-8.2.0.1520-6.8.0.1017-19146.000
    X-TM-AS-Result: No--0.146-5.0-31-10
    X-imss-scan-details: No--0.146-5.0-31-10
    X-TM-AS-User-Approved-Sender: No
    X-TMASE-Version: IMSVA-8.2.0.1520-6.8.1017-19146.000
    X-TMASE-Result: 10--0.146400-5.000000
    X-TMASE-MatchedRID: wjdoQEOKyrZ7ahiNncA4hJpaQZrxtVBsqS91SjnldFIi7hIFpWx7pqbF
          sETXF+9u5V8fgkZZSCU19vcvk7TH/S8xkUATmhC45BgEdUqqANSV8bCk1I9WfnXA+T8YcZkDP/i
        gW2j9KQ2dtSjAL+46o1q6LJohGEOtW5fzCBTKbRONes9LMglhgLejw9iqfGUKR0givuLhSAhBg2
      NqmDTb6Q+gzceqIagHXcAUO5rYRMutSn//sy4xSbAVy0FQT/1xloKBPsyyeoXpAAWYDGUZn3OxN
            uYzUrAfNmDrdAkjVfe9KhpQKnl6nw==
```

I use the code below to write a client to access EWS which works fine as well.
So my only problem is if it is possible to retrieve the original message header? If so, how can I do it? Thanks!

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(@"myUsername", "myPassword");
service.Url = new Uri("https://webmail.domain.com/ews/exchange.asmx");

Folder inbox = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR");
SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter[] { sf });
ItemView view = new ItemView(20);

FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, searchFilter, view);

foreach (EmailMessage item in findResults)
{
// Can process whatever is necessary here                  
}
```

Comment: Managed to solve it. I can retrieve the original message headers which are actually stored as ItemAttachment in the bounced e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

In 2022, To me it seems you are missing this line to load Message headers. EWS being a lightweight service it doesn't load all the info(like body/header) so you need load it with the below line.

```cs
item.Load(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.InternetMessageHeaders));
```

so that it looks something like this:

```cs
foreach (EmailMessage item in findResults)
{
    item.Load(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.InternetMessageHeaders));
    //Then item.InternetMessageHeaders will be populated
     Console.WriteLine(item.InternetMessageHeaders);     
}
```